# is there a way to custom build a container in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would create a custom container and add properties like id to it
I tried doing it like this.
what I would like is to create a container which has a unique id assigned to it.

```
class Tile extends Container
{
  late int id;
 late int position;
  Tile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
}
```

Comment: What will be the use case for id and `position`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom class like:

```
class Tile extends StatelessWidget {
  late int id;
  late int position;
  Tile({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can choose one of the following two codes:

```
class Tile extends Container {
  Tile({Key? key, required int id, required int position})
      : super(
          key: key,
          child: ......,
        );
}
```

or

```
class Tile extends StatelessWidget {
  const Tile({Key? key, required this.id, required this.position})
      : super(key: key);
  final int id;
  final int position;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ......,
    );
  }
}
```